# Facing Cakephp session issue

Tags: session, cakephp

I am using cakephp 2x and facing issues with cakephp session.
And the flow of website is like whenever you register successfully its auto logged-in and redirects to home page.

Here I am using data from cake session like:

```
$this->Session->read('Auth.Front');
```

But it returns different values on register and on login.

So how to debug it ? from where its writing session 'Auth.Front' ?

Answer (score 0):

`AuthComponent` is surely overwriting the `Auth` key with the user data. Try using a different key.

This should work:

```
$this->Session->write('Front',$myData);
$myData=$this->Session->read('Front');
```